# Using data from TextBox and comparing with previous data

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, logic

Using a TextBox to enter data and then using them. For example
I have two fields, one is TextBox where the height will be inserted and another radio button that will be used to select the gender. Height and gender are entered and each time I press the button new data will be used to compare with others already entered, this data will be compared and an average height by gender will be displayed in the page, with a history of data inputted, as well displayed in the page, how can I do this? is it possible to do without database?

The only way I could do that was creating 15 textboxes and store them in 15 different variables, but that seems to be quite wrong. I want to do all this using just one textbox and be able to use this data without getting lost with each button click

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could create a [`List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) and store the entered pairs of height and gender. Each time a pair is entered you can add it to the list and then run through the list using `foreach` to calculate an average height for each gender. Aside: Radial genders are a bit disconcerting. Perhaps _radio_ buttons?

Comment: @HABO yes radio, thanks I will try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is yes, you can use any variable (e.g., an array) to store the data in **memory**.

If you want to persist the data, you will need a database for that.